# Generate list of AD groups not being used anymore using POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of group that is not being used or doesnt contain any members in the result i want to see the following date created, ownership, location in `AD,NAME OF THE GROUP & memberships`

i tried using this

```
$result = $csv | foreach-object {
$group=$_
get-qadgroupmember "$_" -sizelimit 0 -indirect | select-object samaccountname,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all Get- all empty groups from your AD:

```
Get-QADGroup -Empty -SizeLimit 0 | Select-Object Name,DN,whenCreated
```

Include additional properties you want to export in the Select-Object command